# How to build a catwalk in my attic?

Tags: attic

I'm about to have the insulation removed and reinstalled since the old insulation is doing a very poor job. I will have a couple weeks when the insulation will be removed for me to do some improvement in the attic. First thing I'd like to do is to install a better catwalk (the plank is sitting on the rafter next to my white pex tubes) in the all 2x4 attic.

I have some ideas but I'd like to hear what people have. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems like a complete waste of labor and money to "remove and replace" insulation rather than "simply add more insulation."

Comment: I mean, "it's doing a terrible job" because there's quite evidently less than 3.5 inches of it, (we can see the top and sides of 2x4 truss bottom chords) not because of whatever it actually is. I run about 16-18" in my attic. I have witness marks on the truss webs to help put in a thick even layer.

Comment: "build a catwalk"?? if you don't go up there often then I always found two boards moving one at a time works.

Comment: List how you want to do. This isn't a discussion forum.

Comment: Alright, I think I will just put a few 2' x 6' plywood between joist and rafter. Even when covered with the insulation, at least I have something better to step on. Originally, I wanted to build an elevated catwalk but it seems like it was going to take too much work to make sure it is structurally sound.

Comment: No, JACK. My question was specifically asking for advise, not exactly to bring about a discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way I would consider to do.

[image]

Comment: I love the simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

If you feel you need to add a cat walk, it is possible. You will need to add horizontal 2X4s about 4 ft. long, attached to the vertical center "king post" roughly leveled over to the angled brace. The metal boxes should not be a hinderance, the 2X can go on one side and the 3/4" plywood ripped narrow enough to go beside the box and king posts.

DO NOT nail the new framing. The shaking by nailing will cause the drywall fasteners to loosen and that would be very bad. Use screws on everything. 2 to 3, 2 1/2" screws on each end of the horizontals, 2 screws 2" long into the plywood at each horizontal to keep it stable.

FWIW, I did the same thing in my attic, but used a different method. I was doing a lot of work up there, adding speakers for the room below adding circuits elsewhere, etc.

Also, removing the old insulation is a total waste. ANY insulations is good. You need to have more added.

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad you mentioned not to use nail. I just bought a framing nail gun. The reason I want to remove the insulation is because debris from installing the roof and whatever junk up there. I'd like to properly seal all the cracks and make sure everything is good.

Comment: While you're up there, i would seal around all openings that protrude the upper story ceiling  (attic "floor") such as near lights, pipes, vents, that have air gaps between the drywall  and the item. This will make your house more energy efficient. You can also add a different special fire code spray foam for electrical Romex wires in big holes. What you use will depend on what you are sealing.